# Webservice não mostra parâmetros de retorno no WSDL

Tags: web-service

Estou com problemas com um webservice. Quando acessado o WSDL dele, os parâmetros de entrada dos métodos aparecem normalmente, porém os parâmetros de retorno que cada método deve mostrar não estão aparecendo. Só para constar, todos os parâmetros retornam um dataset. Alguém saberia me dizer o que possa estar ocorrendo? Abaixo a codificação WSDL do webservice.

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="BuscarMaterial">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="codMaterial" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="clientType" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="BuscarMaterialResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuscarMaterialResult">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="AuthHeader" type="tns:AuthHeader"/>
<s:complexType name="AuthHeader">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:base64Binary"/>
</s:sequence>
<s:anyAttribute/>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="BuscarFornecedor">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="codFornecedor" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="clientType" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="BuscarFornecedorResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BuscarFornecedorResult">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element ref="s:schema"/>
<s:any/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarMaterialSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BuscarMaterial"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarMaterialSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BuscarMaterialResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarMaterialAuthHeader">
<wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarFornecedorSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BuscarFornecedor"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarFornecedorSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:BuscarFornecedorResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="BuscarFornecedorAuthHeader">
<wsdl:part name="AuthHeader" element="tns:AuthHeader"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SoftExpertSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarMaterial">
<wsdl:input message="tns:BuscarMaterialSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:BuscarMaterialSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarFornecedor">
<wsdl:input message="tns:BuscarFornecedorSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:BuscarFornecedorSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SoftExpertSoap" type="tns:SoftExpertSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarMaterial">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/BuscarMaterial" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:BuscarMaterialAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarFornecedor">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/BuscarFornecedor" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
<soap:header message="tns:BuscarFornecedorAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="SoftExpertSoap12" type="tns:SoftExpertSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarMaterial">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/BuscarMaterial" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
<soap12:header message="tns:BuscarMaterialAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="BuscarFornecedor">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/BuscarFornecedor" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
<soap12:header message="tns:BuscarFornecedorAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SoftExpert">
<wsdl:port name="SoftExpertSoap" binding="tns:SoftExpertSoap">
<soap:address location="http://portal.karcher.com.br/softexpert/softexpert.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="SoftExpertSoap12" binding="tns:SoftExpertSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://portal.karcher.com.br/softexpert/softexpert.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Ainda está com problemas? Tente usar o SoapUI para acessar o wsdl e recuperar os parâmetros.